# Trying to place the following code into a c++ header

Tags: c++, header

I'm working to put a similar string of code into a header so that the bool can be used by multiple .cpp files.  I'm having issues compiling after adding this to the my program and was hoping for some assistance.

Here is the code:

```
BOOL IsUserAdmin(VOID)
{
    BOOL b;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY NtAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
    PSID AdministratorsGroup; 
    b = AllocateAndInitializeSid(
            &NtAuthority,
            2,
            SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
            DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            &AdministratorsGroup); 
    if(b) 
    {
        if (!CheckTokenMembership( NULL, AdministratorsGroup, &b)) 
        {
            b = FALSE;
        } 
    FreeSid(AdministratorsGroup); 
    }

return(b);
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What "issues" are you having?

Comment: first indent your code correctly

Comment: @Borgleader I suspect that in first place, he can't read his own code.

Comment: How is `VOID` defined and how does it differ from `void`?

Answer (score 9):

Function definitions don't belong in the header, because it naturally leads to multiply defined symbols.

You *can* combat this using

- `static` - marking the function declaration+definition as `static` will make it local to the TU (translation unit, i.e. `cpp` file)
- `static inline`
- anonymous namespaces.
  Enclosing it by an unnames namespace like so: `namespace { /*function definition*/ }` also makes it local to the TU
- (hackishly) making it a function template

However, I don't recommend doing this unless there is a benefit to it. You'd have to start worryin about the ODR (One-Definition-Rule) and since you had to ask this question, I'm going to assume that this is a bit beyond your experience with the language.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to put a function definition into a header. You want to put function declaration into a header, like this:

```
BOOL IsUserAdmin(VOID);
```

The definition goes into some source file.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want it in the header?